Should questions of the form "Is X a scam?" be removed?
Example 1
Example 2
These questions frequently don't have definitive answers. They ought to be referred to bitcointalk, which has, literally, an entire section of the site dedicated to accusations of scamming.
"Is X a scam?" has two sorts of useful answers:

Yes, they are a scam, they scammed me, here's my proof.
I think X isn't a scam, because of circumstantial evidence Y and Z.

Second, these questions are much better answered by a forum.

I disagree.
They are often somehow answerable, especially if the answer is "yes".
For instance, if a site asks to hold your money, and you cannot retrieve information about its owner, or it incorporated in a city-state, it is likely a scam to avoid.
Or if a site doesn't put his money where his mouth is (such as GLBSE not being listed on GLBSE itself), it is highly at risk too.

I agree that they can be answered. The issue I have is that they don't have a definitive answer. "Is X a scam?" is a question that can be answered both yes and no at the same time, with each answer being entirely valid.

@NickODell but only one answer will be correct since it either is or is not a scam. Sure, it is more difficult to understand which is the correct one...
